# How do I add a UITabController to certain views but keep hidden in others?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

If you look below it's currently how I have my project set up with a `UINavigation Controller` with segues for each view. I'm looking to throw in a `UITabController` for just The Wall view and upload for now.

[image: The Wall view and upload for now.]

What I've tried:

Selecting the `UINavigationController` using The Embed in `>>` Tab Bar Controller, which implemented a `UITabBarController`, but seemed to add in the Log In view as a tab which I couldn't figure out how to remove or get rid of in both the view itself and in the TabBar.

Also tried selecting Wall View and Embedding in the Tab Bar controller but nothing showed up on the view as far as a `TabBarController` goes...any ideas on how to implement this correctly since I'm using a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do any of that, just drag a new `UITabBarController` over to storyboard, wire it up with your wall and upload view controllers as tabs and make the push segue from your login and signup controllers go to your new tab bar controller.

Comment: Okay so I dragged out a new TabBarController to storyboard, linked both the Wall and Login views by ctrl+drag clicking to the views from the TabBarController, but nothing shows up when I run it on either view. I am not sure what you meant by making the push segues from login and signup go to new tab controller?

Comment: For some reason though, << Login appears in the navigation bar for both of these tab bar views now. I tried hiding this via [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
but didn't seem to work? Tried in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear ?

Comment: That's the expected behavior, if you don't want that I suggest showing the login/register proccess in a Modal Navigation View Controller and when logged, returning to the main navigation where you show the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom method for navigating from the code and when navigating you can write the below code while pushing the viewcontroller:

```
yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES
```